# An Inaccessible JavaScript Object property - Why is Firebug showing this?

Tags: javascript, firebug

So, I'm attempting to access the content of an object and for the life of me can't figure out why I can't.  I'm starting to believe that the object doesn't have the properties that Firebug indicates that it does. More likely than that I'm just not using the right syntax to access them.

Give the following function:

```
function(userData) {
    console.log(userData);   // statement 1
    console.log(userData.t_nodecontent); // statement 2
}
```

Which generates the following FireBug output for statement 1

[image]

and `undefined`  for statement 2.  (Note:  Originally incorrectly indicated that I was seeing `unknown`)

Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking in the way I'm attempting to reference the value of `t_nodecontent`?  I'm at a loss :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unknown` means that its a Host Object, like the ones provided by ActiveXObject in IE.

If there had been no such property, you would have seen `undefined`

So you are accessing its property, it's just has a type not defined by ECMAScript.

Comment: Seems a weird case... I've only seen `"unknown"` as the result of `typeof` operator in some properties of the host objects you mention, but only on **IE**, seems that the OP is using Firefox, and he is just trying to access the property... unusual...

Comment: @CMS, who knows what `console.log` does in the background, we all know that it doesn't just do `toString()`

Comment: I made a mistake :( It actually says undefined.  Will edit the post accordingly.

Comment: so,  If it shows up in Firebug, but I get an undefined when trying to reference it, how does FireBug find it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and write output:

```
for(var key in userData){
   console.log(key, userData[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, you'll find, is that userData is actually [userData]! Try accessing userData[0].
I've been caught like this before (most recently today with an object property of a Dojo.Data item)... if the object is passed in an array, Firebug displays the first element of the array, rather than the array itself.